# using read inside if clause - bash

Tags: bash

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd ]]; then
    echo -e "\nPassword: ${passwd}"
else
    echo -e "\nInput timed out" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

But it gives error:

```
./script.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
./script.sh: line 3: syntax error near `-t'
./script.sh: line 3: `if [[ read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd ]]; then'
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the `[[ ... ]]`.  Simply rewrite it as:

```
#!/bin/bash

if read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd; then
  echo -e "\nPassword: ${passwd}"
else
  echo -e "\nInput timed out" >&2
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

or to be easier to read and/or shorter:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd || echo -e "\nInput timed out" >&2 && exit 1
echo -e "\nPassword: ${passwd}"
exit 0
```

**Update**:

To understand why it works without `[[ ... ]]`, the bash man must be checked:

> **if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi**
>
> The *if list* is executed.  If its exit status is zero,  the *then list*  is  executed.   Otherwise,  each *elif list* is executed in turn, [...]

In this case, The `if list` is the read command.  `[ $? -eq 0 ]` and `test $? -eq 0` are also valid lists with specific exit status.  `[[ expression ]]` (again according to bash's man) is also a valid list, but `read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd` is not a valid expression.  See the man to know what are valid expressions.

Comment: could you explain why it works without `[[ ... ]]`?

Comment: sure, I edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using command inside the `[[ ]]` statement, which makes no sense. This operator should be used like `test` function for checking some condition.

It's better to run `read` command separately and check it's exit code then.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -t 10 -sp "Enter Password: " passwd

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -e "\nPassword: ${passwd}"
else
    echo -e "\nInput timed out" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```